# Form validation on non form field angular2

Tags: angular2-forms

im quite new with angular2, but i seem to manage ok for a beginner. However, i'm stuck on some validation issues. i want to validate a component that is not a form field (e.g. input, select e.t.c).

I'm using a bootstrap dropdown which uses an unsorted list.

dropdownButtons.html

```html
<div class="btn-group" dropdown>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" dropdownToggle  >
    {{ selected  ? selected : 'Type...'}}
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" dropdownMenu>
    <li *ngFor="let value of values;let i = index" (click)="onChange(value)">
      {{value.label}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

dropdownButtons.component.ts

```js
import {Component, EventEmitter, Output, Input, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'dropdown-buttons',
  template: require('./dropdownButtons.html'),
  directives: [DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES]
})

@Injectable()
export class DropdownButtons {

  @Input()
  values: DropdownValue[] = [{ "value": "RSS", "label": "RSS" },{ "value": "REST", "label": "REST" }];

  @Input()
  selected : string;

  @Output()
  select: EventEmitter<DropdownValue>;

  constructor() {
    this.select = new EventEmitter();
  }

  onChange(type) {
    this.select.emit(type);
  }

}

export class DropdownValue {
  value:string;
  label:string;

  constructor(value:string,label:string) {
    this.value = value;
    this.label = label;
  }
}
```

My form looks like this.

```html
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #refererform="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputUrl">Url</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUrl" placeholder="Url" required
             [(ngModel)]="model.url" name="url">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <dropdown-buttons  [(selected)]="model.type" (select)="onSelect($event)" ></dropdown-buttons>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" ng-show="showDetails" *ngIf="isShown()">
      <label for="header">Header</label>
      <textarea placeholder="Default Input" class="form-control" id="header"
                [(ngModel)]="model.header" name="header"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" ng-show="showDetails" *ngIf="isShown()">
      <label for="payload">Payload</label>
      <textarea placeholder="Default Input" class="form-control" id="payload"
                [(ngModel)]="model.payload" name="payload"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" >Submit</button>
  </form>
```

I tried to use ngModel (using required in the tags) and the FormGroup option, where i define some formcontrols. It works fine with form controls, but i can't seem to figure out how i validate non form components, is it even possible?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to validate in this particular use case?

Comment: I would like to create a required validation on the dropdown.so people cannot select the default (null) option

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098355/angular-2-ng-bootstrap-dropdown-with-formcontrolname