# Angular 2 - ng-bootstrap dropdown with formControlName

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Is there a way to make the [ng-bootstrap dropdown control](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown) work with Angular's reactive forms?

Given:

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownMenu1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <button class="dropdown-item">Action - 1</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item">Another Action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item">Something else is here</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can one use the formControlName much like used on inputs?

```
<input formControlName="name" />
```

Comment: Instead of button use `<input type="button" value="" formControlName="name">`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, `ng-bootstrap` dropdown can't be used as a form control out-of-the-box.

But it's possible to create your own component that will be used as a form control. To do it, you need to implement `ControlValueAccessor` interface. You can read more in this article: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html

Answer (score 3):

I've made custom dropdown using ng-bootstrap and I'll give you description how I resolved it.

Change *button* for opening dropdown with *input* tag. Make it *readonly* and add action on *click* to open ngbDropdown (*dropdown.open()* in code example).
For every item in the list add on *click* event to set formControl value.

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-46axva