# Angular - How to add button label value to FormGroup

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am implementing a contact form, which contains inputs and a dropdown selection. For the dropdown, I am using the ng-Bootstrap library, so I have a button as well as the dropdown menu and dropdown items. But in combination with Angular and the FormGroup, it is very hard to add the button label value to it. Could anyone give an advice on how to possibly solve it? Thanks in advance!

Code snippet from HTML file:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label class="input-label" for="topicDropdown">Your Topic</label>
                <div ngbDropdown id="topicDropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-label btn-block btn-outline-secondary" id="topic" ngbDropdownToggle><span class="float-left">{{ selectedCategory }}</span>
                    </button>
                    <div ngbDropdownMenu class="w-100">
                      <a ngbDropdownItem *ngFor="let category of categories;" id="{{category.toLowerCase()}}DropdownItem"
                        name="categoryDropdown" (click)="onCategorySelection(category)"><span class="btn-label">{{ category }}</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>       
            </div>
```

The function in .ts file, I wish the button label or the `selectedCategory` variable could be part of the FormGroup.

```
private setUpValidationForm(){
    this.contactForm = new FormGroup({
      email: new FormControl("", [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.email
      ]),
      firstname: new FormControl("", [
        Validators.required
      ]),
      lastname: new FormControl("", [
        Validators.required
      ]),
      topic: new FormControl(), // This is not working..
      message: new FormControl("", [
        Validators.required
      ])
    });
  }
```

Comment: What exactly are you not able to do?

Comment: I would like to add the value of selectedCategory to the FormGroup, OR the button with ID 'topic' should be within the FormGroup

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42105482/4743730

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Below approach, You update the form on change of the value

```typescript
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="input-label" for="topicDropdown">Your Topic</label>
        <div ngbDropdown id="topicDropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-label btn-block btn-outline-secondary" id="topic" ngbDropdownToggle><span class="float-left">{{ this.contactForm.get('topic').value ? this.contactForm.get('topic').value : 'Select Value' }}</span>
                    </button>
            <div ngbDropdownMenu class="w-100">
                <a ngbDropdownItem *ngFor="let category of categories;" id="{{category.toLowerCase()}}DropdownItem"
                    name="categoryDropdown"
                    (click)="this.contactForm.get('topic').setValue(category)"><span class="btn-label">{{ category }}</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[See this Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-epbkyw) to this solution